# How to keep alive Service which start by Runtime.getRuntime java

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

I start Service.jar (build of spring boot) by java exe comman line

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String command = "java -jar " + rootFolder + serviceFile + " " + additionalEnv;
                if(SystemUtils.checkLinuxPlatform()){
                    command = "nohup " + command + " &";
                }
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

. But when i shutdown java app, service do terminated follow. 
How to keep service running without quit java app or other way start service automation.

Comment: You can create a daemon thread and run `Runtime.getRuntime().exe(cmd) ` on that thread.

Comment: I started Runtime.getRuntime().exe(cmd) on that thread but same issue is happen

Comment: Try to use a `Process` instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exe(cmd)` and call `waitFor()` on that process.

Comment: I used and same issue is happen.

Comment: In the example that you've added, the thread doesn't seem to be set as daemon, you need to call `thread.setDaemon(true)` in order to do that.

Comment: Sorry i miss. But the way is failure :(